# A variable in angularjs is not updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs, setinterval, angularjs-digest

I tried to create a timer using AngularJs, but when I increment the timerCount inside the setInterval method, the value changes but the view doesn't update with the new value.
When I checked the console log, I found out that timerCount increments as it should, and if I click the button again, timerCount takes the current value in the view.
How can I make the view change each second?

here is the html :

```
<p>timer count: {{timerCount}}</p>
  <button ng-click="startTimer()">start timer</button>
```

and the controller:

```
var app=angular.module('examApp',[]);
    app.controller('examCtrl',function($scope){

        $scope.timerCount=0;
        $scope.startTimer=function(){
            setInterval(function(){
                console.log($scope.timerCount);
                $scope.timerCount++;
            },1000)
        }
    })
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/CScdb8QFSFpKR7WJWuQJ?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any function which update angular scope `variable/bindings` outside the angular context will not intimate angular to run digest cycle, resultant the binding wouldn't get update on the HTML.

Here you are using `setInterval`(this doesn't initimate angular to run digest cycle) which is native JavaScript function which runs asynchronously, and you are trying to update the scope value from this function. You should use `$interval` instead of using `setInterval`.

Basically `$interval` service uses `setInterval` internally but the callback function has been wrapped inside `$rootScope.$evalAsync` which runs digest cycle for you on each interval.

**Code**

```
app.controller('examCtrl',function($scope, $interval){

    $scope.timerCount=0;
    $scope.startTimer=function(){
        $interval(function(){
            console.log($scope.timerCount);
            $scope.timerCount++;
        },1000)
    }
});
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/HZ1rMAthy9tJZRupfLkQ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Togeter with Pankaj's answer you could use this too, because when used pure js along with Angular You need to use **$apply** method  like

```
$scope.startTimer=function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            console.log($scope.timerCount);
            $scope.timerCount++;
            $scope.$apply();
        },1000)
    }
```

then it will work as expected.